# X-axis labels not printing on Base Plotting System On R

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

"R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)"

I have a some time-series data where I am trying to look at the change in  consumption over time. Here is a reprex.

```
set.seed(1)
date <-  seq(as.POSIXct('2010-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2010-04-10'),by=86400)
Consumption <- rnorm(99)


Data <- data.frame(date,Consumption)


plot(Data$Consumption~Data$date,type='l') # X-axis labels and ticks not printing
par(yaxt='n')
axis(side = 2,at=seq(-3,3,0.5),labels = seq(-3,3,0.5)) # This works on the first  plot on the y axis



plot(Data$date~Data$Consumption,type='l') # X-axis refusing to print despite assigning it.
par(xaxt='n')
axis(side = 1,at=seq(-3,3,0.5),labels = seq(-3,3,0.5)) # This works on the first  plot
```

The graph outputted in the  initial `plot()` is exactly what I want except for the fact it doesn't have any labels for the x-axis.

I am using Base Plotting   for an assignment rather than everyday use and would usually use ggplot.
I have been trying to figure out why the x-axis is not plotting. Initially I thought the problem was with the date variable and tried cleaning it up with `lubridate::ymd()`. However when I started making the above reprex for the  purpose of  this question it is clear to the X-axis labels and ticks as whole is not printing. In the  second plot I put the consumption variable on the x-axis. I was surprised to find that the  date is printing neatly on its own on the Y-axis.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want more control over what happens with axis labels and title, you could create them manually. So, first produce a plot without title and label. Then, create them manually with `axis()` and `mtext()`. In the process, you may increase the room at the bottom of the plot with `par(mar=...)`. Finetuning is done with arguments like `las`, `cex.axis`, and  `line`. And at the end, you reset `mar` to its old values.

You could use the code below to get more detailed X-axis labels

```
### format to day (probably not the best way to do this) 
Data$date2 <-format(Data$date, "%d%b")
Data$date2 <- as.Date(Data$date2, format = "%d%b")

### increase room at bottom of the plot for X-axis title
### the labels will eat up space, if we do nothing it will be a mess
### set title with mtext later
par(mar = c(7,4,4,2))

### plot without X-axis labels (xaxt) and title (xlab)
### work with "at" and "labels" in axis-function
### rotate labels 90° (las) an reduce font (cex.axis)
### put title 5 lines below graph (line)
###
### Remark: the graph window has to be big enough
plot(Data$Consumption ~ Data$date, type= "l", xaxt = "n", xlab = NA) 
axis(side = 1, at = Data$date, labels =  Data$date2, las = 2, cex.axis=.75)
mtext(side = 1, text = "Date", line = 5)
```

This yields the following graph:

[image]

**ALTERNATIVE**
ticks and labels for every 7th item

```
per7 <- seq(1, 99, 7)
plot(Data$Consumption ~ Data$date, type= "l", xaxt = "n", xlab = NA) 
axis(side = 1, at = Data$date[per7], labels =  Data$date2[per7], las = 2, cex.axis=.75)
mtext(side = 1, text = "Date", line = 5)

### reset mar
par(mar = c(5,4,4,2))
```

which gives the following picture:

[image]

Please let me know whether this is what you wanted.

Comment: Please note, when we include two plots your solution still produces the error: `Data$date2 <-format(Data$date, "%d%b")
Data$date2 <- as.Date(Data$date2, format = "%d%b")
par(mar = c(7,4,4,2))
plot(Data$Consumption ~ Data$date, type= "l", xaxt = "n", xlab = NA) 
axis(side = 1, at = Data$date, labels =  Data$date2, las = 2, cex.axis=.75)
mtext(side = 1, text = "Date", line = 5)
plot(Data$date ~  Data$Consumption, type= "l", xaxt = "n", xlab = NA)`

Comment: I do not get any error on my side. What is the error message?

Comment: No such error message. Whenever we plot two charts within a chunk, the second one will always miss labels. But if you place each chart in different chunk it is going to run correctly to display axes labels correctly.

Comment: @doctshinds 
1.I dont think Consumption has to be 100 values- R literally complains about that.

2. I understand now what the  problem is. `par() ` doesn't reset with every plot which 
somehow doesn't makes sense to me. I Once i reset everything it worked like a charm. 


@KoenV
The graph works as expected.
 if you read above , i realised the problem lies in having to reset par() with every plot.  And seems putting `xaxt='n'` on `par()` makes it more permanent and requiring to be reset with `xaxt='s'`. Keeping it within the 'plot()' call changes things per plot.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues I can see readily:

1. change: Consumption <- rnorm(99) to Consumption <- rnorm(100) to
   match date column.
2. The problem is with 'par'. When there are multiple plots within a chunk, unlike ggplot, plot does not handle properly. Remove par and run the below it should work

```
    set.seed(1)
    date <-  seq(as.POSIXct('2010-01-01'),as.POSIXct('2010-04-10'),by=86400)
    Consumption <- rnorm(100)
    Data <- data.frame(date,Consumption)
    plot(Data$Consumption~Data$date,type='l') 
    plot(Data$date~Data$Consumption,type='l')
```

Please note whenever you define par and when you run each plot in two different chunks, the labels will display properly. You will not have any issue. But when you plot both the charts in a single chunk, you will always have problem if you have par.